# word wrapping in MAC machines

Tags: html, css

I am building a form using Bootstrap3. However just one word in a checkbox label is wrapping to the next line **only for MAC safari/chrome machines**. For all others including IE, windows etc, it looks ok

The word is the **plush** in the first checkbox [here](http://staging.serviceportal.com.au/service05/plush_form.do)

The html is

`<label for="custom9">Have you received your entire order from Plush?</label`>

Comment: Try adding white-space: nowrap; attribute to the class.

Comment: Thanks I needed both the display:block and the white-space:nowrap to make this work. Cheers

Comment: OK. i will add it as an Answer for future references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

attribute to the class.